# Firebase Security Rules Correct Format

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

Are these rules in correct format? When I put them in Database Rules, I see red dashed lines which may indicate an error/warning but when I hover over it, I receive no feedback.

```
{
  "rules": {

    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
        ".read": "auth !== null"
      }
    },

    "usernames": {
      "$userName": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "root.child('usernames').child($userName).child('uid').val() == auth.uid || root.child('usernames').child($userName).child('uid').val() == null",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
        ".read": "auth !== null"
      }
    },

    "following": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
        ".read": "auth !== null"
      }
    },

    "followedBy": {
      "$fid": {
        "$uid": {
          // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
          ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
          // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
          ".read": "auth !== null"
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

This is what I see:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen those too. Pretty much as soon as I add an empty line.

I think the empty lines are just causing a false error indicator to show up.

Since nothing's failing (at least not for me as far as I can see), I wouldn't worry about them.

Comment: The reason I asked is that I followed the instruction in the manual link given above, and it doesn't show the Facebook and Email(Google) button for OAuth (for login). I wonder if you would know the reason to that.

Comment: wow! I just realized I talked to a Firebase Engineer! Is there a slack room I could show the screenshots of the problem I am facing? Basically even when I create a manual account by clicking on sign up, nothing happens.

Comment: The security rules can not cause a button in your app to be not showing. While the code and the rules should go hand in hand, there is no explicit connection between them. If you're having trouble getting buttons to show, it's easiest to help if you show the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would apply in our community slack channel too, for which you can sign up through: firebase-community.appspot.com

Answer (score 3):

To reformat your code rules and make it read able
Just copy your rules and then go to [JS cleaner](https://html-cleaner.com/js/) and  click claen Js re copy and past into your database rules